# Spark s3 csv files read order

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say three files in s3 folder and whether read through spark.read.csv(s3:bucketname/folder1/*.csv) reads the files in order or not ?
If not, is there way to order the files while reading the whole folder with multiple files received at different time internal.

| File name | s3 file uploaded/Last modified time |
| --- | --- |
| s3:bucketname/folder1/file1.csv | 01:00:00 |
| s3:bucketname/folder1/file2.csv | 01:10:00 |
| s3:bucketname/folder1/file3.csv | 01:20:00 |

Comment: How is the received time specified? Is it a column in your data or is it something like a timestamp on the file?

Comment: this is s3 file uploaded time / last modified time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achive this using following

1. Iterate over all the files in the bucket and load that csv with adding a new column `last_modified`. Keep a list of all the dfs that will be loaded in `dfs_list`. Since pyspark does lazy evaluation it will not load the data instantly.

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucketname')

dfs_list = []

for file_object in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="folder1/"):
    df = spark.read.parquet('s3a://' + file_object.name).withColumn("modified_date", file_object.last_modified)
    dfs_list.append(df)
```

2. Now take the union of all the dfs using pyspark `unionAll` function and then sort the data according to `modified_date`.

```py
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

df_combined = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs_list)

df_combined = df_combined.orderBy('modified_date')
```